# How to calculate Mean Sample-Based Reliability Estimates Used for Analyses

Tags: mean, meta-analysis, reliability, pearson-r, fisher-transform

I am conducting a meta analysis of Pearson's r , of correlations presented between test scores and job performance ratings. I need to present an uncorrected effect size and an effect size corrected for reliability. I understand that some studies present inter rater reliability estimates but some do not. I am wondering how I can calculate such estimates of reliability without inter rater reliability information please?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what mean sample-based reliability estimates used for analyses are and what relationship this question has to meta-analysis?

Comment: Of course , I am conducting a meta analysis with moderators of pearsons r correlations. I need to calculate the reliability estimates for groups of these correlations (or facets). E.G - I have separated correlations of test scores and job performance into groups of job , task , contextual and managerial performance.

Comment: What role are those reliability estimates going to play in the meta-analysis? If you have multiple estimates for each primary study would you not be better off doing a multivariate meta-analysis?

Comment: Thanks but I do not have multiple estimates for each primary studies , there are only 5 out of 30 studies with multiple correlations.

Comment: The reliability estimates would need to be calculated as the studies do not report inter rater reliability, so to  correct for unreliability in the criterion

Answer (score 1):

If you have some estimates you have several options:

Re-run your meta-analysis using a range of plausible reliability estimates based on the range of the ones you do have. If your results are substantively similar over that range then you can be happy.

Choose a typical reliability value to represent the ones you have. The median would seem a reasonable choice but you could average them (after first using Fisher's transformation and then back-transforming).

Comment: Thanks , and pardon my ignorance as I am a Novice. So if I average them using Fishers z , from the available estimates, how do I then apply them to the calculated effect sizes , or produce a set of corrected effect sizes?

Comment: You need to read some of the work by Hunter and Schmidt or use software which implements it. Sorry but it is not a technique which I have ever had to explore.